# What kind of a visa do I require to halt at Kuala Lumpur for 3 days while travelling from Mumbai to Melbourne via Kuala Lumpur?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, malaysia

I am travelling to Melbourne, Australia from Mumbai, India. I have a valid visa for Australia. I am planning to go visa Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia and halt for a 3 day visit.

My question is, what kind of a visa do I require? The ENTRI Visa seems to require a return ticket back to India. Also, if I apply for a transit visa, it is not clear whether it would allow me a 3 day halt at Malaysia.

Second question is, how do I apply? There are just so many websites that it is really confusing.

http://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/visa/types-of-visa.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the visa before 31st December 2018, you can apply for

> **Visa Waiver Program (eNTRI) for Indian Nationals.**
>
> This program is extended until 31st Dicember 2018.

What is eNTRI?

> **What is eNTRI?**
>
> Electronic Travel Registration & Information (eNTRI) is an online registration facility provided by the Government of Malaysia to facilitate the entrance of Indian Nationals into Malaysia under the Visa Waiver Programme. An eNTRI Note will be issued as proof of the registration and it is required to be presented upon arrival in Malaysia.

You're right, eNTRI does seem to have that restriction

> Applicants residing inside India must have a direct flight from India to Malaysia and direct return flight ticket from Malaysia to India or via Singapore, Thailand or Brunei by air OR land is permitted to enter Malaysia and exit Malaysia via the following Entry/Exit points:

[Source](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/FAQ/PDF/FAQ/About/eNTRI/eNTRI_Indian_Nationals_en.pdf?version=1.4)

**You can simply get an eVisa**

> **What is eVISA?**
>
> eVISA is an online application platform that enables foreign nationals to apply for an electronic visa to enter Malaysia at the comfort of your convenience.

[Source](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/FAQ/PDF/FAQ/About/eVISA/eVISA-About_en.pdf?version=2.1)

---

[**Apply Here**](https://www.windowmalaysia.my/evisa/evisa.jsp) in both cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Yes, as per the website, I need a single entry eVisa (SEV). I was a bit unsure about the authenticity of the website but thanks a lot for verifying it.

I found one website with a similar name (www.windowsmalaysia.com) which seems to be a scam.